# Perl: open files from array and read one by one

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have an array in Perl that looks like this:

```
 my @dynfiles = ('dyn.abc.transcript', 'dyn.def.transcript', 'dyn.ghi.transcript', 'dyn.jkl.transcript');
```

I'm trying to open these files and read them one by one. For this I have a code that looks like this:

```
foreach my $dynfile (@dynfiles) {
    print "$dynfile\n";
    open my $fh , '<', $dynfile or die "Could not open file\n";
    my %data;
    $data{$dynfile} = do {
        local $/ = undef;
        while (my $line = <$fh>) {
            chomp $line;
            if ($line =~ m/Errors:\s+0/) {
                print "Dyn run status: PASS\n";
            } else { 
                print "Dyn Run status : FAIL\n";
            }
        }
        close $fh;
    }
}
```

And I get this error as output:

```
dyn.bxt.transcript
Dyn run status: FAIL
dyn.cnl.transcript
17:25:19 : -E- Could not open dyn.cnl.transcript
```

So my concern is that it isn't reading the files in the array at all. Also, this file `dyn.bxt.transcript` had this string `Errors : 0` in it, but I still get `Dyn run status: FAIL` in the output. 
Am I doing anything wrong here? I'm using a simple pattern match, not sure where the problem is..Kindly help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Matching is case sensitive, or you could add the `/i` flag. Also, please format your code with proper indentations.

Comment: if there is a space between `Errors` and the semicolon, it won't match your regex.

Comment: There is a space between them. It looks like this: 'Errors  :  0' . What would be the best way to do the regex then?

Comment: You could do `m/Errors\s*:\s*0/i` as long as the number isn't 0 padded. Something like `Errors : 05` would still match it for a false positive. Another way you could do it is `m/Errors\s*:\s*(\d+)/i` to capture the number in `$1` and check if that is `0`.

Comment: There is no zero padding. All I have is just this string 'Errors  :  0'.                           m/Errors\s*:\s*0/i or m/Errors\s*:\s*(\d+)/i still does not work :(

Comment: I started a chat room, join and I'll help you debug: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72962/perl-open-files-from-array-and-read-one-by-one

Comment: @chiIemagic..I do not have enough credit points to talk in the chat room :(

Comment: Since you're setting `$/` to slurp mode with `undef`, you can remove the `while` loop and the `chomp`, since it's only ever going to read one record and `chomp` shouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After viewing reading your code and debugging in chat, I would probably go with something like this:

```
sub dynamo_check {

    opendir(my $dh, $log_file) or die "can't opendir $log_file: $!";
    my @dynfiles = grep { /^dynamo.*transcript$/ && -f "$log_file/$_" } readdir($dh);
    close $dh;

    foreach my $dynamofile (@dynfiles) {
        print "Checking file: $dynamofile\n";

        open my $fh, '<', $log_file . $dynamofile or die "$!\n";

        my $passed = 0;

        while(my $line = <$fh>) {
            if ($line =~ m/Errors\s*:\s*0/i) {
                $passed = 1;
                last;
            }
        }
        if ( $passed == 1 ) {
            print "Dynamo run status: PASS\n";
            $data{$dynamofile} = "pass";
        }else {
            print "Dynamo run status: FAIL\n";
            $data{$dynamofile} = "fail";
        }
    }
    print Dumper(\%data);
}
```

Summary of changes:

- Add on `$!` to get a better error message as reference in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)
- Use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) to find the files you want to read instead of hard coding it.
- Prepend the directory path to the file name when we open the files.
- Remove the `do` block;
- Set the values in `%data` to `pass` or `fail`.
- No need to use [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) here.
- No need to set `local $/ = undef;`, we can go through the lines one by one and break out of the `while` loop with [last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) when we find the `Errors` line.

Comment: @chilemagic..This was really useful and worked for me! I'm trying the same logic in the other subroutines that I had like we discussed on chat and I'm facing an issue..let me know when you are free for a quick chat again? :)

Comment: Hey @chmod, post what information you have about the issue in the chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72962/perl-open-files-from-array-and-read-one-by-one and I'll take a look at it today or tomorrow!

Comment: @chilemagic..was finally able to correct the script..Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

First, let Perl tell you why it couldn't open a file:

```
open my $fh , '<', $dynfile or die "Could not open file $!\n";
```

I notice that your error message references *dyn.bxt.transcript* and *dyn.cnl.transcript* that are not in your `@dynfiles`. It helps is you build a complete and minimal script with sample inputs.

Then you are undefining the input record separator, after which you use a `while` which should only ever return the single line of the entire file. That's typically a bad thing.

Next, if looks as if your pattern doesn't match the string `Errors : 0` that has a space in it.

```
        if ($line =~ m/Errors\s*:\s+0/) {
```

I'm not sure what you're doing with the `do`. That returns the last evaluated expression, which in your case is `close $fh`. But, that `%data` hash disappears at the end of each iteration of the block. Again, strip out everything that isn't part of investigating this problem.

Comment: you are right about the pattern match - yes there is a space in this string that I had missed: 'Errors : 0' and the regex you suggested works!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the code using some well tested modules. For example using one of my favourite [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), you could write:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;

my @dynfiles = map { "dyn.$_.transcript" } qw(abc def ghi jkl);
say "Dyn run status: ",
    (path($_)->slurp =~ /error\s*:\s*0\b/i)
        ? "PASS"
        : "FAIL"
    for (grep {-f} @dynfiles);
```